# Why the prefix @ is needed in `date -d @1270787111`?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to convert epoch time to human readable format. I search on the Internet and found a

Example :`date -d @1270787111`.

I reread the manual of date.

> -d, --date=STRING  display time described by STRING, not 'now'

And

> DATE STRING
>          The --date=STRING is a mostly free...

I found nothing about this format. Do I miss something?

Comment: As to *why* it is needed: `date --date 20130607` is a legal representation of today's date, so something is needed to differentiate a compressed YYYYMMDD date from a true integer timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same “DATE STRING” section that you are referring to ends with the following sentence:

> The date string format is more complex than is easily documented here
>   but is fully described in the info documentation.

In other words, you have to refer to "info" pages. You can do so by typing `info date` in your terminal, or take a look at those documents online. Input formats are well described [here](http://www.cs.vassar.edu/cgi-bin/info2www?%28coreutils%29Date%20input%20formats), for example.

So why the prefix `@` is needed in `date -d @1270787111`? The particular format with `@` as mentioned in a manual page example is [described in §28.8](http://www.cs.vassar.edu/cgi-bin/info2www?%28coreutils%29Seconds%20since%20the%20Epoch):

> ## 28.8 Seconds since the Epoch
>
> If you precede a number with `@', it represents an internal time stamp
>   as a count of seconds.  The number can contain an internal decimal
>   point (either`.' or `,'); any excess precision not supported by the
>   internal representation is truncated toward minus infinity.  Such a
>   number cannot be combined with any other date item, as it specifies a
>   complete time stamp.
>
> Internally, computer times are represented as a count of seconds
>   since an epoch--a well-defined point of time.  On GNU and POSIX
>   systems, the epoch is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, so `@0' represents this
>   time,`@1' represents 1970-01-01 00:00:01 UTC, and so forth.  GNU and
>   most other POSIX-compliant systems support such times as an extension
>   to POSIX, using negative counts, so that `@-1' represents 1969-12-31
>   23:59:59 UTC.
>
> Traditional Unix systems count seconds with 32-bit two's-complement
>   integers and can represent times from 1901-12-13 20:45:52 through
>   2038-01-19 03:14:07 UTC.  More modern systems use 64-bit counts of
>   seconds with nanosecond subcounts, and can represent all the times in
>   the known lifetime of the universe to a resolution of 1 nanosecond.
>
> On most hosts, these counts ignore the presence of leap seconds.
>   For example, on most hosts `@915148799' represents 1998-12-31 23:59:59
>   UTC,`@915148800' represents 1999-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, and there is no
>   way to represent the intervening leap second 1998-12-31 23:59:60 UTC.

Answer (score 0):

> Dates can be entered via integer counts of seconds since 1970 when
>     prefixed by `@'.

from [coreutils 5.3.0 release](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2005-01/msg00041.html) .

So this

```
date -d @1270787111
```

means describe data that is 1270787111 seconds away since epoch (1970/01/01).

Answer (score 0):

> DATE STRING
>          The --date=STRING is a mostly free format human  readable  date  string
>          such  as  "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29 16:21:42" or
>          even "next Thursday".  A date string may contain items indicating  cal-
>          endar  date,  time of day, time zone, day of week, relative time, rela-
>          tive date, and numbers.  An empty string indicates the beginning of the
>          day.   The date string format is more complex than is easily documented
>          here but is fully described in the info documentation.

from the bottom of the man page

```
info coreutils 'date invocation'
```

Should give you the info you need

Date input formats

> - General date syntax::          Common rules
> - Calendar date items::          19 Dec 1994
> - Time of day items::            9:20pm
> - Time zone items::              EST, PDT, GMT
> - Day of week items::            Monday and others
> - Relative items in date strings:: next tuesday, 2 years ago
> - Pure numbers in date strings:: 19931219, 1440
> - Seconds since the Epoch::      @1078100502
> - Specifying time zone rules::   TZ="America/New_York", TZ="UTC0"
> - Authors of parse_datetime::    Bellovin, Eggert, Salz, Berets, et al